# Issues after installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I installed Nvidia graphics drivers on Ubuntu 20.04. After rebooting the graphics drivers are loaded. But `wlan` and `eth0` interfaces are not up!

Comment: Can you try `sudo ifconfig [network-interface] up`?

Comment: Tried but eth0 interface not found..:(

Comment: Just do `ifconfig -a` to find out about your interfaces.